# JS / jQuery - launch function upon page-load AND every x seconds AND upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to launch an AJAX call that refreshes a table for the FIRST time upon page load, but from then onwards need it to run every XX seconds, but also whenever a user presses the "refresh" button.

Now I dont want to make 3 copies of the same code and bind it to 3 different launchers, whats the best way to approach this?

This here runs every 5 seconds but NOT upon page load or button click

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        var prevAjaxReturned = true;
        var xhr = null;

        setInterval(function() {
            if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
                prevAjaxReturned = false;
            } else if( xhr ) {
                xhr.abort( );
            }

            xhr = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'refresh_rescap_reqs',
                    holidex: '<?php echo($_SESSION['Holidex']); ?>',
                    access: '<?php echo $_SESSION['Access']; ?>'
                },
                //dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#Last20Requests').html(data);
                    prevAjaxReturned = true;
               },
            });

        }, 5000);   // 1000ms = 1 sec
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap the ajax call in a function and call this function 3 times ?

Comment: What's the problem in using 1 function, bind in 3 different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the ajax call in a function and call this function 3 times

```js
$(function() {
    var prevAjaxReturned = true;
    var xhr = null;

    var repeatFunction = function() {
        if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
            prevAjaxReturned = false;
        } else if( xhr ) {
            xhr.abort( );
        }

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
            data: {
                action: 'refresh_rescap_reqs',
                holidex: '<?php echo($_SESSION['Holidex']); ?>',
                access: '<?php echo $_SESSION['Access']; ?>'
            },
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Last20Requests').html(data);
                prevAjaxReturned = true;
           },
        });

    };
    repeatFunction();
    setInterval(repeatFunction, 5000);   // 1000ms = 1 sec
    $("#reload").on('click', repeatFunction);
});
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="reload">Reload</a>
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the button as it reload the entire website instead of just the function / ajax call...? I believe the issue to be that `<button>` must be defined as `type="button"` as it otherwise will trigger a submit.

Comment: oh...yeah...then you can use anchor tag on the button

Comment: hmmm... still cant get the button to work. With `type="button"` in use, the console returns an error saying that the function reference doesnt exists. With the `type` attribute, the whole page reloads...?

Answer (score 3):

just bind your function to a variable and you can reuse it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
    var prevAjaxReturned = true;
    var xhr = null;

    var functionToRun = function() {
        if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
            prevAjaxReturned = false;
        } else if( xhr ) {
            xhr.abort( );
        }

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
            data: {
                action: 'refresh_rescap_reqs',
                holidex: '<?php echo($_SESSION['Holidex']); ?>',
                access: '<?php echo $_SESSION['Access']; ?>'
            },
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#Last20Requests').html(data);
                prevAjaxReturned = true;
           },
        });

    };

    setInterval(functionToRun, 5000);   // 1000ms = 1 sec
    $(document).on('click', functionToRun);
    functionToRun();
});
```